# How to capture text that are inclosed between two same simbols?

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I have a string:

```
'PROTEIN\t1\t0\ttr|Q6ZN40|Q6ZN40_HUMAN\t\t-1\t;;;;;'.
```

And I need to capture the text between two |. So it would be 'Q6ZN40'.

I tried this code for that:

```
re.match('|(.+?)|', string).group(0)
```

but it gives me an empty string: ''.

What is wrong with my code ? I presume that the regex is not correct but I don't understand why..

Comment: You have to escape the pipe and get group 1 instead of 0 `\|(.+?)\|` https://regex101.com/r/MhAqf5/1

Answer (score 1):

You could use [re.search](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search) instead because [re.match](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.match) starts at the beginning of the string.

To match the pipe literally you have to escape it `\|` and the value will be in the first capturing group `.group(1)`

```
\|(.+?)\|
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/MhAqf5/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/Vo0pG5)

For example

```
import re

regex = r"\|(.+?)\|"
string = "PROTEIN\\t1\\t0\\ttr|Q6ZN40|Q6ZN40_HUMAN\\t\\t-1\\t;;;;;"
print(re.search(regex, string).group(1))
```

Output

> Q6ZN40

A more efficient match would be to use a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) matching any char except a `|` to prevent unnecessary backtracking (The pipe does not have to be escaped in the character class)

```
\|([^|]+)\|
```